# Visualización en 3D de las columnas de un dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, visualización-de-datos

Quiero hacer una visualización en 3D de las columnas beta1, beta2 y cost del siguiente marco de datos.

```
>>> df_thetas_value.head()
    beta0   beta1   beta2   cost
0   0.511275    0.404934    0.783799    2.820328e+07
1   34.486883   123.591098  143.711200  1.122274e+06
2   36.435332   163.909685  118.786188  8.688915e+05
3   40.692430   204.987832  113.643168  8.072207e+05
4   42.270578   237.838460  91.286946   6.112149e+05
```

Entonces queria hacer como en [este articulo](https://jackmckew.dev/3d-terrain-in-python.html#3d-terrain-in-python), pero hay un problema: los i,j no son int en mi caso. Entonces me devuelve `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices` Pensaba buscar por el index de las posiciones en un sorted marcos de datos.

```
def get_sorted_index(df, value):
    index = df.sort_values().index[df.sort_values()== value].tolist()[0]
    return index

world = np.zeros((len(df_thetas_value), len(df_thetas_value)))
for index, row in df_thetas_value.iterrows():
    i,j = row["beta1"], row["beta2"]
    i = get_sorted_index(df_thetas_value['beta1'], row["beta1"])
    j = get_sorted_index(df_thetas_value['beta2'], row["beta2"])
    world[i][j] = row["cost"]
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
>>> matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(world,cmap='terrain')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## plot_surface

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

## Matplotlib Sample Code using 2D arrays via meshgrid
X, Y = np.meshgrid(df_thetas_value['beta1'].values, df_thetas_value['beta2'].values)
Z = df_thetas_value['cost'].values
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.title('Original Code')
plt.show()
```

Pero Z no esta en la buena diemnsion. Todos los elementos necesitan haber un tamano de 2. En efecto, esto devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-b836e6304023> in <module>
     14 ax = Axes3D(fig)
     15 surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
---> 16                        linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
     17 ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
     18 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py in plot_surface(self, X, Y, Z, norm, vmin, vmax, lightsource, *args, **kwargs)
   1554 
   1555         if Z.ndim != 2:
-> 1556             raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")
   1557         if np.any(np.isnan(Z)):
   1558             cbook._warn_external(

ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.
```

## plot_trisurf

Tambien intenté:

```
ax.plot_trisurf(df_thetas_value['beta1'].values, df_thetas_value['beta2'].values, df_thetas_value['cost'].values, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.2)
plt.show()
```

Pero no se muestra nada.

## griddata

Al final hizé:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# 2D-arrays from DataFrame
df = df_thetas_value
x1 = np.linspace(df['beta1'].min(), df['beta1'].max(), len(df['beta1'].unique()))
y1 = np.linspace(df['beta2'].min(), df['beta2'].max(), len(df['beta2'].unique()))

"""
x, y via meshgrid for vectorized evaluation of
2 scalar/vector fields over 2-D grids, given
one-dimensional coordinate arrays x1, x2,..., xn.
"""

x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)

# Interpolate unstructured D-dimensional data.
z2 = griddata((df['beta1'], df['beta2']), df['cost'], (x2, y2), method='cubic')

# Ready to plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(x2, y2, z2, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.title('Meshgrid Created from 3 1D Arrays')

plt.show()
```

Pero solo se muestra el background:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir "Una visualización 3D de las columnas beta1, beta2 y cost"? Quiero decir, qué iría en el eje X, en el eje Y y en el eje Z de esa visualización?

Comment: @abulafia Si! Ejacatemente

Comment: Fijate que tu df no contiene suficientes datos. Quiero decir, para cada valor de beta1, necesitarías tener un valor de coste para cada posible valor de beta2.  Un ejemplo, si beta1 tomara los valores 1,2,3 y beta2 lo mismo, necesitarías 9 valores de cost, uno para cada pareja (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3). Si no, no puedes crear una superficie 3D

Comment: Gracias @abulafia, trataré de encontrar una manera de generarlos todos entonces